# PLS-00302: component must be declared I dont understand why i get this error

Tags: sql, oracle

I start learning sql and i dont understand why i have the error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE direccion AS OBJECT (
    calle         VARCHAR2(25),
    ciudad        VARCHAR2(20),
    codigo_post   NUMBER(5)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE persona AS OBJECT (
    codigo      NUMBER,
    nombre      VARCHAR2(35),
    direc       direccion,
    fecha_nac   DATE
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_alumno AS OBJECT (
    al      persona,
    nota1   NUMBER,
    nota2   NUMBER,
    nota3   NUMBER
);
/

DECLARE
    p   persona := persona(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    dir   direccion := direccion(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    al    t_alumno := t_alumno(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
BEGIN
    al := t_alumno(persona(2, 'ALBERTO', direccion('DDDD', 'CIUDAD', 88), sysdate), 5, 10, 7);

    dbms_output.put_line('NOMBRE: '
                         || al.p.nombre
                         || ' * CALLE: '
                         || al.p.direc.calle);

    dbms_output.put_line('NOTAS: '
                         || al.nota1
                         || ' * '
                         || al.nota2
                         || '*'
                         || al.nota3);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not used the `type` correctly at two places in your first `dbms_output`.

It should be something like the following:

> ```
> SQL>
> SQL> DECLARE
>   2      p   persona := persona(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
>   3      dir   direccion := direccion(NULL, NULL, NULL);
>   4      al    t_alumno := t_alumno(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
>   5  BEGIN
>   6      al := t_alumno(persona(2, 'ALBERTO', direccion('DDDD', 'CIUDAD', 88), sysdate), 5, 10, 7);
>   7
>   8      dbms_output.put_line('NOMBRE: '
>   9                           || al.al.nombre -- replaced p with al here
>  10                           || ' * CALLE: '
>  11                           || al.al.direc.calle);  -- replaced p with al here
>  12
>  13      dbms_output.put_line('NOTAS: '
>  14                           || al.nota1
>  15                           || ' * '
>  16                           || al.nota2
>  17                           || '*'
>  18                           || al.nota3);
>  19
>  20  END;
>  21  /
> NOMBRE: ALBERTO * CALLE: DDDD
> NOTAS: 5 * 10*7
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

the name for `persona` member in `t_alumno` is `al` and not `p`

```
dbms_output.put_line('NOMBRE: '
                         || al.al.nombre -- <- here is a bug al.p.nombre
                         || ' * CALLE: '
                         || al.p.direc.calle);
```